# Count same string in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count how many times same string happens in 30 different cells.

Example:

```
"kat"
"hund"
"kat"
"mus"
"hund"
"kat"
```

I tried `Countif(A1:A6,"kat")`. It shows "3" because "kat" appears 3 times. After that I would make a line with "hund" and one with "mus". This does not work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the column next to it put: `=COUNTIF(A$1:A$6,A1)` (or `=TÆL.HVIS(A$1:A$6,A1)` in a Danish Excel)
Drag that down, and you'll get:

```
kat   3
hund  2
kat   3
mus   1
hund  2
kat   3
```

With a slight modification you can figure out the n'th occurence of a word, just use `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)`, which would give:

```
kat   1
hund  1
kat   2
mus   1
hund  2
kat   3
```

For future reference: [Names for Excel functions in English and Danish](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=dansk-english.html), [Official list of Danish Excel functions](http://office.microsoft.com/da-dk/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP010079186.aspx#BMstatistical_functions). Click on the function in the official list to get more information and to make sure you get the correct name (the overview misses "." in some functions).

Comment: What error do you get? You could also try `=COUNTIF(A:A;"="&A1) `instead of `=COUNTIF(A:A;A1)`, but as far as I know both should work in excel 2007. I unfortunately cannot test this as I only have excel 2010 installed here.

Comment: My excel is in danish and i just writes "#NAVN?"
danish, Navn = Name, english.
when i try evaluate where it fails it says "COUNTIF"

Comment: Try replacing COUNTIF by TÆLHVIS

Comment: Strange, that error usually indicates that the function you're trying to use doesn't exist. Maybe I typed something wrong or it doesn't work to copy/paste it... In any case, here is the official list of functions in the Danish version of Excel: http://office.microsoft.com/da-dk/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP010079186.aspx#BMstatistical_functions Try to find the function for COUNTIF and enter that one in the field. The arguments of the function should still work (you might need ";" instead of ","; depending on your country).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already nearly correct, let's assume you have Column A full of Animals (30)

Now you need 3 Formulas, one for each animal.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A30;"hund")
=COUNTIF(A1:A30;"kat")
=COUNTIF(A1:A30;"mus")
```

the A1:A30 defines the range and the name in " behind the :  defines the word you search for
[image: see I fastly did it]

Comment: Instead of "COUNTIF" i use "TÆL.HVIS" then it works.

Comment: probably next time tell us that you are using not the english version :)